# Why is so slow to load data into mysql table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, mariadb

It takes several hours to load a file with 3 millions record, and each column only consists of two fields, ID and Name. Does the slowness have something to do with the relationship with other tables? The data table I am loading is a intersection table in a many-to-many relationship:

```
MariaDB [wordDS]> describe Category_Term;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| categories_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| terms_id      | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The two IDs are simply foreign keys to primary keys of the parent tables, Category and Term. When I load the primary tables, it seems much faster. Do you think the loading becomes slower due to the foreign reference? Or it has nothing to do that.

This is more info and hope it helps.

```
MariaDB [wordDS]> show processlist;
+----+----------+-----------+------------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id | User     | Host      | db         | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  3 | ling | localhost | wordDS | Query   |    0 | init         | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
|  9 | ling | localhost | wordDS | Query   | 2564 | reading file | LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C_T01.txt' INTO TABLE Category_Term FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINA |    0.000 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Any comments or knowledge about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is checking the `FOREIGN KEYs` as it loads the rows.  This means looking in the other two tables.

- Do they have suitable indexes?
- Are the columns the same datatype?
- How big are those indexes compared to `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?